# Themed Text control doesn't work in QML Application

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a simple application with the following QML

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Column {
        Text {
            text: "Hello World"
            color: "red"
            font.pixelSize: 24
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 1
            color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to package up the text and the rectangle into a control for reuse. So I created a QML document called `Label.qml` with the following content

```
Item {
    property alias text: text.text
    Column {
        Text {
            id: text
            color: "red"
            font.pixelSize: 24
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 1
            color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

And refactor the application as follows,

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Label {
        text: "Hello World"
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work, the text in the refactored version is unstyled, and the rectangle does not appear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Problem reason` The type name of your custom component `Label` is clashing with the `Label` control that is available because of `import QtQuick.Controls` statement in your file.

`Solution` Change the name of your custom qml type to some another name. Ex: `MyLabel`

That's it.